# Flutter app not receiving test notifications from Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send notifications to an iOS device that is connected to my computer from Firebase Compose message section. The Flutter app is started using `flutter run`.

Push Notifications, Background fetch and Remote notifications are enabled in XCode and Apple Push Notifications service (APNs) key created and uploaded to Firebase

[image]
[image]

main.dart file :

```
class NotificationService {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  void init() {
    _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(); // Request permission for iOS

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      // Handle foreground messages
      print(
          "Message received: ${message.notification?.title} - ${message.notification?.body}");
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      // Handle user taps on a notification
      print("Message clicked!");
    });
  }

  Future<String?> getToken() async {
    return await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
  }
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  try {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error during Firebase initialization: $e");
  }
  // debugPrintRebuildDirtyWidgets = true;
  NotificationService().init();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

sign-in-screen.dart - I'm not sure if I should ask for permission in both places, but I have users that are logged in already and want them to allow notifications
```

Future requestNotificationPermission() async {
NotificationSettings settings =
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(
alert: true,
badge: true,
sound: true,
provisional: false,
);

```
  if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
    print('User granted permission');
  } else if (settings.authorizationStatus ==
      AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
    print('User granted provisional permission');
  } else {
    print('User declined or has not accepted permission');
  }

  return settings;
}

signUserIn() async {
  try {
    UserCredential userCredential =
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: userNameController.text.trim(),
      password: passwordController.text.trim(),
    );

    _authStateChangesSubscription =
        FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) async {
      if (user != null && user.uid == userCredential.user?.uid) {
        NotificationSettings settings =
            await requestNotificationPermission();

        if (settings.authorizationStatus ==
                AuthorizationStatus.authorized ||
            settings.authorizationStatus ==
                AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
          // User granted permission
          String? token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
          if (token != null) {
            await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .doc(user.uid)
                .update({'fcmToken': token});
          }
        }
        ...more code
```

So the issue is that even though I see the fcmToken being saved in Firestore, I can't send any notifications. Nothing prints in main.dart ... I really don't know how to debug this or how to check what might be wrong.